# Subscribe to a folder with MS graph SDK

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

How can I make it work with the Microsoft Graph SDK (.Net and C#) that I can only subscribe to one folder ? (I want to code a webhook based on this).

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get() {
      var graphServiceClient = GetGraphClient();
      var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
      
      sub.ChangeType = "updated";
      sub.NotificationUrl = config.Ngrok + "/api/notifications";

      sub.Resource = "/drives/{driveID}/root/";
      sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
      sub.ClientState = "SecretClientState";

      var newSubscription = await graphServiceClient.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(sub);
```

So far I can only subscribe to everything in the root but not to a specific folder in Onedrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, On personal `OneDrive` you could subscribe to the `root folder` or any `subfolder` within that drive but in `OneDrive` for business, you could only subscribe to `root folder`. Let me know if you required further assistance on this.

> ***Note:*** You cannot subscribe to drive or driveItem instances that are not folders, such as individual files. You could refer to our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#driveitem).

So you can create folder within the root, in that case you could allow your user to  create folder where they can upload their files.

Hope it would helps

Comment: I have also had to find that out. Strange I can only subscribe to the root directory but a MS Graph delta queries can be made in any popular folder.

Comment: Yes you can have queries on folder and even can upload files on any folder as well but need to be under root.